# Can Google Find device triangulate location of my phone by cell tower signal?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, geolocation, lost-phone

I know it wouldn't be precise but can I find my [Not] lost Android 6.0.1 Lenovo P1a41 Turbo by Cell tower signals using Google Find Device ?

If not, can any other app do that ?

Comment: They don't actually use cell towers but they do. Every android has implemented feature to locate phone, of Google  services are installed. Howeverou lost phone location must be turned on on device (maybe on newer versions it doesn't need to be) if no then bye bye, also it could help if phone is on WiFi but if phone is not locked from factory reset, then someone just wipes phone and only way to trace it is IMEI and police can do that but in most cases they don't bother.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје it's nice to have connections from the police especially when your grandpa was Chief Of The Police !

Comment: Well that's sad in one hand, using police for your own needs. But whatever.